# Generate custom icon ionic2 login error

Tags: angular, cordova, web-applications, ionic2, apache-cordova

im trying to generate a custom icon for my webapp, but i'm getting this error when i'm trying to log into my ionic account:

[errormessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0gox.png)

I don't understand this, beacuse i have an account and my eMail and password is correct.

I do it with the command "ionic cordova resources --icon".

Can anyone help me?

Comment: provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be… Minimal, Complete, Verifiable --- https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: what happens if you type `ionic link`.  (in order to link this current project)

Comment: @PhilipBrack the same error appears..

Comment: really seems like your account with them is different than the one you type in.  Its been a while since I used their services. is there an ssl cert you have to associate.  These days I do all on my ionic development using my own resources.

Comment: @PhilipBrack that's right, but i can login on the ionic website with the same credentials without any problem..
Yeah maybe i should do this too. It's not tha kind of a big deal, i just wanted to test this, because it's my first development with ionic.

thanks for your help

Comment: I just realized all you are trying to do is get your icon and not use ionic.io  That should be possible I do not recall logging in for that. I will take a look when off of work.

Answer (score 0):

Below I am using $ sign for the terminal prompt.

```
$ionic start check_icon blank
$cd check_icon/
$cp ~/Downloads/icon.png resources/
$cp ~/Downloads/splash.png resources/
$ionic cordova platform add ios android
$ionic cordova resources
✔ Collecting resource configuration and source images - done!
✔ Filtering out image resources that do not need regeneration - done!
[OK] No need to regenerate images--source files unchanged.
```

When I created the platforms it correctly generates the resources. I ran on my phone to verify my icon and splash. It works!

At no time during all of this have I connected to the ionic services. I would suggest performing these steps in a new area to verify it works with your icon, then diff your projects to see if there are any hints.

Here is my configuration.

```
$ionic info
ionic info

cli packages: (/Users/pbrack/.nvm/versions/node/v8.5.0/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.13.1
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.13.2

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.0
    Cordova Platforms  : ios 4.5.2
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1

System:

    ios-deploy : 1.9.2
    ios-sim    : 5.0.8
    Node       : v8.5.0
    npm        : 5.4.2
    OS         : macOS Sierra
    Xcode      : Xcode 9.0 Build version 9A235

Misc:

    backend : legacy
```

Answer (score 0):

@PhilipBrack this is what i'm trying to do, but when i entered the command this appears in the console:

```
[WARN] You need to be logged into your Ionic account in order to run ionic cordova resources.

Log into your Ionic account
If you don't have one yet, create yours by running: ionic signup

? Email:..
```

So it looks like i have to login to generate an icon.

Comment: Maybe i've found the problem. My ionicPro account is the version for free so i can't use their developing servers